# Is there a way to override line ending used by BufferedReader?

Tags: java, android

I am writing a parser for an ad-hoc line-based protocol so the functionality of the `BufferedReader.readLine` method fits perfectly.

But I have a certain requirement that line ending must be exactly `\r\n` and errors should be thrown (or other parsing logic applied) if only `\r` or `\n` is found.

So is there a way to enforce this without rolling a custom line-splitting implementation?
If not, what's the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

Well you could potentially override `readLine()` itself - but you'd basically have to reproduce all the code within it. There's nothing that can be tweaked *just* for the purposes of changing the line ending.

Given that your code wouldn't have direct access to the buffer, I suspect you'd actually have a simpler time implementing a completely new class which potentially *read* from a `BufferedReader` in order to avoid having to do much buffering yourself. (i.e. just buffer for the duration of the `readLine` method, rather than having a buffer within the instance.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way but scanning the lines for invalid character sequences. This can either be done by overwriting the method `readLine()` from `BufferedReader` (as Jon metioned) or do this in your reading class.